RestAssured - Test Containers Post call "java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed. Expected status code <201> but was <404>."
I've been receiving 'No static resource api/order' when running the tests. I'm using test-containers. Previously, it was running normally; I added the handling to use WireMock to create a mock of an HTTP call. When debugging, it passes through the stubs but encounters the error with status code 404.
I'm using a random port by setting AutoConfigureWireMock, then I created a resources folder within the test with inventory.url=http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}
import com.levi.microservices.order.stub.InventoryStubs;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MySQLContainer;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
class OrderServiceApplicationTests {

    @ServiceConnection
    static MySQLContainer mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.3.0");
    @LocalServerPort
    private Integer port;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost";
        RestAssured.port = port;
    }

    static {
        mySQLContainer.start();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldSubmitOrder() {
        String submitOrderJson = """
                {
                     "skuCode": "rtx4060",
                     "price": 1000,
                     "quantity": 1
                }
                """;

        InventoryStubs.stubInventoryCall("rtx4060", 1);
        var responseBodyString = RestAssured.given()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .body(submitOrderJson)
                .when()
                .post("/api/order")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .statusCode(201)
                .extract()
                .body().asString();

        assertThat(responseBodyString, Matchers.is("Order Placed Successfully"));
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderController {

    private final OrderService orderService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        orderService.placeOrder(orderRequest);
        return "Order Placed Successfully";
    }
}

Properties:
#SPRING Configurations
spring.application.name=order-service

#SERVER Configurations
server.port=8081
server.servlet.context-path=/api
inventory.url=http://localhost:8082

#MYSQL Configurations
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/order_service
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.levi.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>order-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>order-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Verify endpoint configuration, syntax and verified RestAssured and others dependencies.
